# Hierarchy of Including css files in laravel to avoid css overriding

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm not too much familiar with the front end development since I've worked as back-end developer. Now, I've a problem with css overriding on my page.

I've following a structure including css files in the master layout.

```
@section('assets')
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Raleway:300,400,500,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/animate.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@show()
```

Whenever the home page is loaded then I have a lot of errors displayed in the console.

> Unknown property ‘-moz-osx-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped. font-awesome.min.css:4:662
>
> Error in parsing value for ‘-webkit-text-size-adjust’.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:7:329
>
> Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-search-cancel-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.min.css:7:1619
>
> Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration dropped.
>   bootstrap.min.css:7:2379
>
> Unknown property ‘widows’.  Declaration dropped.
>   bootstrap.min.css:7:2388
>
> Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.
>   bootstrap.min.css:7:3249
>
> Error in parsing value for ‘margin-top’.  Declaration dropped.
>   bootstrap.min.css:7:21595
>
> Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.
>   bootstrap.min.css:7:21882
>   ....

As per my knowledge, this is because of conflict of css rules added in files and hence proper ordering of the including css files that master blade needs.

Can anyone provide how to reorder the including css files in above master layout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try like: `<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">,      <link href="{{ asset('css/animate.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">,      <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">,      <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">,         <link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">,  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">,   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Raleway:300,400,500,700,800" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @HirenGohel Still same errors and warnings

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
<link href="{{ asset('css/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/animate.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Raleway:300,400,500,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: @SagarGautam check it line by line i mean leave first 2 line and remove below line of css and check what you are getting if every thing is fine add another line this continue untill all line check . it think error occur becuase of css/style.css and css/app.css

Comment: I'll see about this

Comment: @SagarGautam if you like my answer upvote it. may it help other

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't find the way to get out of this problem. This error making page loading too much slow.